# Android NDK OpenGL ES 2.0 Texture Pitch

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, pbo

Is there any way to blit a texture in opengl es 2.0 with a pitch that differs from its width.  Normally I would fix this by using a PBO or adjusting the GL_PACK_ROW_LENGTH via glPixelStore.  However it seems neither GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER for binding a buffer to or GL_PACK_ROW_LENGTH exist on the Android platform.

glTex(Sub)Image2D does not support this.

Any tips?

Comment: Answer my own question here.

In some scenarios this can be solved by adjusting texture coordinates.  Lets say I have a 512x512 texture pitched at 512*bitdepth but the data I want to use is pitched to 256*bitdepth.    I go ahead and glSubTexImage2D still but adjust the texture coords to be 0 to (256/512) instead of 0 to 1.  In other words strip off the part of the texture I'm not using.

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer below?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I answered it in a comment here is a more direct answer:

```
// width and height is 256 and max is 512
// texture coordinates
float uMax = (width / max);
float vMax = (height / max);

_texCoords[0] = 0.0; _texCoords[1] =  vMax;
_texCoords[2] = uMax; _texCoords[3] =  vMax;
_texCoords[4] = 0.0; _texCoords[5] =  0.0;
_texCoords[6] = uMax; _texCoords[7] =  0.0;
```

Now use these texcoords to render and you can stick a 256x256 texture in a 512x512 buffer.  The width and height you want to use can be any size equal to or below your max size.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting @[Halsafar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/543700/halsafar)

> In some scenarios, this can be solved by **adjusting texture coordinates**.

---

Lets say I have a **`512`** x **`512`** texture pitched at **`512`** * ***`bitdepth`***

but the data I want to use is pitched to **`256`** * ***`bitdepth`***

I go ahead and `glSubTexImage2D` still but adjust the texture coords to be **`0`** to (**`256/512`**)

instead of **`0`** to **`1`**.

In other words ***strip off the part of the texture I'm not using***.

Comment: Thanks for posting this.  I'm sorry I let it die.

I've edited my question to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

it might sound a bit overkill (or even not so fitting to your expectation), but maybe you could simply take advantage of the rasterizer and Frame-buffer objects : 
create a FBO with the texture as the color buffer and... draw in it some textured quad(s) thanks to a trivial vertex+fragment shader : where you would use a simple Ortho. projection matrix in the vertex shader and use a Point-sampling texture sampling in the fragment shader.